# When to call "Consume" in PlayStore's in-app purchases

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Consumable items require a call to consumeAsync() on the client-side for the purchase to be acknowledged and for the item to be made available for sale again.
Judging by google's integration guide, developers are expected to first deliver the content, then to call consumeAsync(). Is it a common practice to do so or we are supposed to do it in reverse order?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way, but you should make sure that if your app failed to deliver the content it will keep trying until it succeed.

It is much safer to call consumeAsync() when you are sure that content delivery was a success. Because it is the worst experience to have to deal with angry paying customers if you have a problem in your code.